# PHP mkdir issue

Tags: php, php-5.2

`mkdir("/people/jason", 0700, TRUE);`

TRUE = Recursive in PHP 5 and the server is running 5.2.5 but I get:

```
Warning: mkdir() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in 
/home/net1003/public_html/admin/_createPage.inc on line 5
```

Comment: Can you show any of the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2):

are you running this particular script through the command line interface instead? it's possible that version of PHP 4, whereas the mod_php version is 5.

Answer (score 0):

That is all of my code.

I want to create a directory on the web server after a user is added to the MySQL database.
Each user gets their own directory with a default index.php page and I am trying to do this programatically rather than manually.

Comment: can you post the relevant portions of _createPage.inc, also, please post the output of phpversion();